# SwiftUI Pizza Button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wonder if it's possible to create
so-called "pizza button", which is per se a round view divided in 4 halfs(buttons) diagonally with one more button in center.
Each piece should be clickable

ZStack not working, because only on top button view is clickable.
Please give me a suggestion how can i do this.

[image: "pizza button"]

My test code: and assets

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Menu")
                        .frame(width: 88, height: 44)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Settings")
                        .frame(width: 88, height: 44)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                })
                
              
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            
            ZStack {
    
                Button(action: {
                    print("1")
                }, label: {
                    Image("left_btn")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .border(.green)
                        .frame(width: 215, height: 215)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("2")
                }, label: {
                    Image("top_btn")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 215, height: 215)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .border(.yellow)
                })
               

                Button(action: {
                    print("3")
                }, label: {
                    Image("right_btn")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 215, height: 215)
                        .border(.purple)
                })

                Button(action: {
                    print("4")
                }, label: {
                    Image("bottom_btn")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 215, height: 215)
                        .border(.blue)
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("5")
                }, label: {
                    Image("center_btn")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 87, height: 87)
                        .border(.orange)
                })
            }
        }
        .background(.red)
    }
}
```

[image: left]
[image: center]
[image: right]
[[image: top][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz6Vt.png)]
[image: left]

Comment: Consider making a single button that chooses one of five actions depending on the location of the touch.

Comment: Definitely wouldn't do this with `Image` if given the choice, but if you had to, you'll likely need to define a `contentShape` for the `Button` so that they register touches in specific areas.

Comment: This is more something that should be done with `Shape` and then add a tap gesture.

Comment: @Caleb what do you mean by `location of the touch`

Comment: @GrandSirr A location (`CGPoint`) is passed into `onTapGesture`, so it'd be easy to compare that to, say, the center of the pizza button, calculate the distance and angle, and then switch on those to decide what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, using assets is not the right way to solve this problem.

I used `Arcs` to draw `Pizza Shapes` and `SFSymbols` for the arrow images.

Here's how it looks like:
[image: pizza]

`Pizza Shapes` are responsive, but the small circle is not, but you can easily fix this using `GeometryReader`

the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var clicked = false
    var body: some View
    {
        ZStack {
            Color.brown.ignoresSafeArea()
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                Group {
                    PizzaButton(type: .down)
                        .foregroundColor(clicked ? .teal : .white)
                        .opacity(clicked ? 0.7 : 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("click")
                            clicked.toggle()
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                                clicked = false
                            }
                        }
                    PizzaButton(type: .up)
                    PizzaButton(type: .left)
                    PizzaButton(type: .right)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .animation(.interactiveSpring(), value: clicked)
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center) // you can use GeometryReader to make these sizes responsive.
                    .foregroundColor(.init(white: 0.98))
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 4)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.init(white: 0.28))
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}

struct PizzaButton : View {
    let type : ButtonType
    let alignment : Alignment
    let edge : Edge.Set
    let arrowDirection : String
    
    init (type : ButtonType) {
        self.type = type
        switch (type) {
        case .up:
            alignment = .top
            edge = .top
            arrowDirection = "up"
        case .right:
            alignment = .trailing
            edge = .trailing
            arrowDirection = "forward"
        case .left:
            alignment = .leading
            edge = .leading
            arrowDirection = "backward"
        case .down:
            alignment = .bottom
            edge = .bottom
            arrowDirection = "down"
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
                PizzaButtonShape(type: type)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                    .background(PizzaButtonShape(type: type)) // this is required because .stroke clears the shapes background.
                Image(systemName: "arrow.\(arrowDirection)")
                    .foregroundColor(.init(white: 0.35))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(edge, geo.size.width / 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PizzaButtonShape : Shape {
    let type : ButtonType
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let startAngle : Angle
        let endAngle : Angle
        
        switch(type) {
        case .up:
            startAngle = .degrees(225)
            endAngle = .degrees(315)
            break
        case .down:
            startAngle = .degrees(45)
            endAngle = .degrees(135)
            break
        case .right:
            startAngle = .degrees(315)
            endAngle = .degrees(45)
            break
        case .left:
            startAngle = .degrees(135)
            endAngle = .degrees(225)
            break
        }
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.height / 3, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)
        
        return path
    }
}

enum ButtonType {
    case left, right, up, down
}
```